# Assign Category to multiple already existing Discussions

Tags: discussion-board, community-site

I am dealing with Community Sites in SharePoint 2013. I have a Discussion Board with multiple discussions in it, all of them with a blank Category field associated.

I've created a Category and I would like to assign / attach this attribute to all the discussions in the discussion board. I cannot find any reference to this, is there a quick way to proceed?

One more thing; Is it normal that the default list "Discussion List" in the site is empty, even if the discussion board contains multiple elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to update all the discussions to bind the category values is through PowerShell Script.

Comment: Thank you, if I do not have the possibility to run PowerShell scripts, is there other method?

Comment: The other option is through Quick Edit option using spreadsheet format.
Go to list items view -> Select all the item -> Select List Tab in the Ribbon -> Quick Edit.
It will open the list item in a spreadsheet format. Make the necessary changes and click on Stop editing this list at top.